# CodeIgniter Get Session Data for users logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a small site hosted, and I know how to get the session data of a user that's logged in, but lets say I have two different users that login to the site how can I store that into a global like `$_SESSION['userName'];`

So What's happening right now is that, if I get the session data from a logged in user it only returns that user. If this makes sense.

```
public function login_user()
{
  $user_login=array(

  'email'=>$this->input->post('user_email'),
  'password'=>sha1($this->input->post('user_password'))

    );

    $data=$this->User_model->login_user($user_login['email'],$user_login['password']);

      if($data)
      { 
        $this->session->set_userdata('userName',$data['userName']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('email',$data['email']);

        $this->load->view('user_profile.php',$data);


      }
      else
      {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Error occured,Try again.');
        $this->load->view('login.php');

      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set only one user can login at a time in one browser.
If you need to login with another user account you must need to open in another browser.
May be if you need to know how may users logged in

application/config/config.php file:

set **sess_driver** option as **database**.

Make sure you have import the **ci_session** table.

FYI: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html